# Switching traffic by API version

Tags: java, api, rest

I am working on a REST API, which is provided by a Java Spring Boot application. My idea is to have some kind of reverse proxy like Apache Server, that would switch the traffic according to API version parameter in the HTTP Requests to the right backend server, which provides the implementation. However I have no experience with this kind of traffic switching. Do I need some Apache Server plugin for Apache Server to do this or is there some better solution, like NGINX? Or is there any standard solution to accomplish this?

Comment: is the API version number in the URL, or QueryString or is it in message body?  Our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) can do back-end reverse proxy switching based on headers, request line etc, but not message body (although a filter plugin could do this).